# Casting pandas float64 to string with specific format

Tags: python, pandas

I have very small numbers in one pandas column. For example:

```
0      6.560000e+02
1      6.730000e+02
2      6.240000e+02
3      1.325000e+03
4      1.984500e+07
```

Unfortunately, when I cast it to a string, it gives me unusable values, such as:

```
 df.astype('str').tolist()
['8.494e-07', ]
```

Is there a way to return the actual value of an item when casting to a string, such as:

```
'0.0000008494'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
# s = df[c]
s

0    6.560000e+02
1    6.730000e+02
2    6.240000e+02
3    1.325000e+03
4    8.494000e-07
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

You can either call `str.format` through `apply`,

```
s.apply('{:.10f}'.format)

0     656.0000000000
1     673.0000000000
2     624.0000000000
3    1325.0000000000
4       0.0000008494
Name: 1, dtype: object

s.apply('{:.10f}'.format).tolist()
# ['656.0000000000', '673.0000000000', '624.0000000000', 
#  '1325.0000000000', '0.0000008494']
```

Or perhaps, through a list comprehension.

```
['{:f}'.format(x) for x in s]
# ['656.000000', '673.000000', '624.000000', '1325.000000', '0.000001']
```

Notice that if you do not specify decimal precision, the last value is rounded up.